# Why does my game run fine on Linux, but not in Windows? (Java .jar)

Tags: java, linux, windows, multithreading, jar

When deploying my game in a .jar, it runs fine with no errors on Linux / Mac.

However on Windows, (specifically testing Windows 10 as of yet), I get these errors on launch and then a blank screen in my JFrame:

```
Exception in thread "PooledThread7" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Buffers have not been created
    at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.getBackBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.getBackBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.flip(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.show(Unknown Source)
    at engine.Game$Render.render(Game.java:250)
    at engine.Game$Render.run(Game.java:167)
    at engine.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:89)
```

and

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: res\maps\map.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at engine.testMapCreator.init(testMapCreator.java:69)
    at engine.Game.init(Game.java:126)
    at engine.Game.main(Game.java:80)
```

So it appears Windows is not liking my thread pool rendering, and for some reason while it finds the map files inside a .jar on Linux, it does not find them when on Windows.

... So much for "Write once, Run anywhere", right? What could be the problems?

edit: This is how I am reading the map.txt files:

```
InputStream is = Game.class.getResourceAsStream("/map.txt")
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is);

(for loops to iterate over the data)
```

Comment: The error is not in reading, but in *writing* to `res\maps\map.txt`

Comment: That part is fixed, however that is a minor issue. The first issue is the main problem. So far I have just put the rendering method in a try catch catching the IllegalStateException however now the frame flickers while spamming the error in the console. It seems as if only every few frames gets through the try-catch block.

Answer (score 0):

1. For the first error probably adding `-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false` to the command line will help (disable usage of Direct3D for 2D rendering). E.g.:

   java -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false -jar some.jar
2. As for the second one, we would need to see how you write the files (FileWriter is mentioned), it might be e.g. that you don't have `res\maps` directory.

Comment: I write the files using a BufferedWriter, and read the Files using an  InputStream and Scanner.

Comment: It doesn't matter which classes you use, but how you use them, the actual code would be helpful.

Comment: @MitchWeaver Does the command line option help with the first problem?

Comment: Sort of, it slows the rate of errors coming, but it also drops the frame rate drastically, (200+ down to ~16 fps). I don't think it actually helps the problem